# How to get quoted String from retrofit 2 response?

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

Right now I am getting the response in this way:

> response.body = {users=[{identity=poJwA, firstname=abc, lastname=abac,
>   email=abac@abc.com,
>   profile_image=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/talent-advocate/default-avatar.png},
>   {identity=AbwOA, firstname=abcd, lastname=efgh, email=jayhghl@o2h.com,
>   profile_image=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/talent-advocate/default-avatar.png}

And i want response in quoted String like:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "identity":"pdavp",
         "social_media":"twitter",
         "is_company":0,
         "site_identity":0,
         "active":1,
         "created_at":{
            "date":"2018-09-21 05:39:07.000000",
            "timezone_type":3,
            "timezone":"UTC"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

So that I can convert into my JSON Object.

Or can I convert response  into my custom model which is different from API response?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the raw response on a retrofit call, you'll need to add the Scalars converter.

In your `build.gradle` file add:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.4.0'
```

Then when you build your retrofit instance, add the converter:

```
val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(URL)
            .client(OkHttpClient.Builder().build())
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create()) // Add this line
            // Other converters or callbacks.
            .build()
```

This way you'll be able to access the raw String and handle the json any way you prefer.

But as a suggestion, take a look at [Moshi from Square](https://github.com/square/moshi) (or GSON), you'll be able to convert your API JSON responses directly to your Java/Kotlin objects, and there's a converter for that too, you'll just need to add the dependency:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.3.0'
```

And then add the converter to retrofit:

```
.addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
```

Comment: i have used GsonConverterFactory

Comment: GsonConverterFactory won't give you the raw String, if you really need that String, you'll have to use the Scalars converter and tell Retrofit that you'll be expecting a String.

Comment: @tyson Do you really want the raw string, or do you want the model object? If the latter, you don't need the scalars converter but you can just use the GsonConverterFactory. In your API interface, have the call return something like `Call<MyPOJO>`

Comment: I'm guessing a bit without seeing what your interface file looks like. By this I mean the file where you likely added a `GET("/.../")` annotation to some method, and it should return `Call<Something>`?